# if $f$ is measurable real valued function on $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ then $f^{-1} (B)$ is borel set for every borel set in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I am trying to find a counterexample to show that not necessary if $f$ is measurable real valued function on  $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$  then $f^{-1} (B)$  is borel set for every borel set in $\mathbb{R}$. I know that if $f$ is countinous then $f^{-1} (B)$ is borel set for every borel set in $\mathbb{R}$. and we know if $f$ is measurable not necessary to be measurable.

Comment: Presumably you mean $f$ is Lebesgue measurable? Take the indicator of a set that is Lebesgue measureable but not Borel measurable.

Comment: yes lebesgue measurable .how can i construct this indicator which is not borel ?@copper.hat